# Backupchain bandwidth calculation

Tags: ftp, hyper-v, bandwidth

we have 7 servers being backed up right now using backup chain locally for about a year now. I have tried the FTP backup on one of our financial number crunch VMs to move it offsite to our other office and it has been working great. I am not a big ftp expert hence a little question

Question: we currently have upload isp speed 10 mega bits and we plan to back all the VMs over the wire. total size of our VMs right now is 600GB and of course growing
do you think we need a better isp to back this whole thing up over night?
How much bandwidth should we buy to get this to work smoothly?

Answer (score 4):

I shouldn't have to do this for you, but here we go anyway:

```
10Mbps == 1.25MB/sec
600GB  == 614400MB

614400MB / 1.25MB/sec = 491520 Seconds
  491520 / 60         = 8192 Minutes
    8192 / 60         = 136.53 Hours
  136.53 / 24         = 5.68 Days
```

You're [gunna need a bigger boat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gciFoEbOA8) if you want to transfer that sort of data regularly. But if you're doing full backups over the wire, you're crazy. You want to do one full backup and then just the deltas (incremental backups).

Problem's going to be that you're going to have 6 days worth of changes queued up while the initial copies go over.